# why would a variable nested inside a JavaScript loop have a different effect than when outside?

Tags: javascript, loops

I was trying to print a grid of 4*8, I have done everything as I should. the following code was run but it produced something totally different than I expected.

```js
var x = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  x = " " + x;
  for (var j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
    x = x + "#";
  }
  console.log(x);
}
```

but when I put the var x = ""; inside the first for loop, the outcome was a correct 4*8 grid like the following:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  var x = "";
  x = " " + x;
  for (var j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
    x = x + "#";
  }
  console.log(x);
}
```

I do not really understand why would that make a difference when it's in or out the loops, and if so, why does it need to be inside the first loop but not the seconds.

Comment: It's not where you put `var x` that's important, it's where you put `x = "";`. The `var` declaration is interpreted as if it occurred outside the loop either way, but the initialization (or re-initialization) is what counts.

Comment: PS: This `var x = "";
  x = " " + x;` can be written `var x = " "; `

Comment: Just to add to @Pointy s answer: the search term you are looking for is _variable scope_.

Comment: @Paul: not really, since the scope of `x` is the same in both examples? Of course it's never wrong to learn about scope :)

Comment: I recommend to learn about how to debug JavaScript with your browser. Then set a breakpoint and step through code. Seeing  the step by step execution and inspecting the variables hopefully helps understanding the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You have faced difference because you **re-assign value of x in each iteration of outer for loop** when you pass `var x = ""` into for-loop body.

However in first code sample ( execute `var x = ""` before for-loop) you are initialize `x` as global variable and won't re-assign it's value( you have assigned value `""` to `x` only once).

Answer (score 0):

Though the already posted answer and comments are all true and pertinent, I guess your incertainty about what happens is not totally solved so.

Look at this numbered version of your first version of code:

```
1. var x = "";
2. for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
3.   x = " " + x;
4.   for (var j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
5.     x = x + "#";
6.   }
7.   console.log(x);
8. }
```

In fact, from the way you ask it, I think that you had the (false) idea that, while iterating the external `for()` loop (#2 to #8), the #3 affectation gives a *totally new* value to `x`, as if nothing had happened to it inside the internal `for()` loop (#4 to #6).
Probably because you heard something about "isolation" of variables inside a block.

But you must realize that this "isolation" regards only variables *declared inside* of the involved block!
A the opposite, your `x` have been declared early, so it changes continuously during whole execution, *including during internal loop execution*: it's not a new one at each external loop step as you seemed to expect!